# How do I change the font color upon the expiration date?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

I want set color when the expiration date has not yet been reached green. But when the expiration date is red

```css
.curentDate {
    color: rgb(54, 168, 54)
}

.expirationDate{
    color:  red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col">
    <h5 for="maintenancePackage">Maintenance Package</h5>
    <p class="{{ setexpirationDate(ticket) }}">{{ getMaPackage(ticket) }}</p>
</div>
```

app.ts

```
  setexpirationDate(ticket) {
    let color = ''
    const endDate = moment(ticket.site.maEndDate.seconds * 1000).format('L');
    const currentDate = new Date()
    const currentDateFormat = moment(currentDate).format('L');
    if (endDate < currentDateFormat) {
      color = 'curentDate'
    } else {
      color = 'expirationDate'
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the `ticket` from template? Is it a variable from a `*ngFor` array?

Comment: you dont need the `.format('L')` as you are using moment use the [.diff](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/)

Comment: you are using a local variable `color`. where are you using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the color variable

```
setexpirationDate(ticket) {
    let color = ''
    const endDate = moment(ticket.site.maEndDate.seconds * 1000).format('L');
    const currentDate = new Date()
    const currentDateFormat = moment(currentDate).format('L');
    if (endDate < currentDateFormat) {
      color = 'curentDate'
    } else {
      color = 'expirationDate'
    }
    return color // you need to return the value
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong.

```
if (endDate < currentDateFormat) {
      color = 'curentDate'
    } else {
      color = 'expirationDate'
    }
```

You are setting trying to set the color **green** when the date is expired and **red** for the opposite.

#### Solution:

**HTML:**

```
<p [ngClass]="{isExpired?'expirationDate':'currentDate'}">{{ getMaPackage(ticket) }}</p>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
get isExpired() {
    let color = ''
    const endDate = moment(ticket.site.maEndDate.seconds * 1000).format('L');
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentDateFormat = moment(currentDate).format('L');
    return endDate < currentDateFormat;
  }
```

Comment: you can use [ngClass] as `[ngClass]="isExpired?'expirationDate':'currentDate'"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding !important on the color?
e.g

```
.expirationDate{
    color:  red !important;
}
```